# How to change progressbar Status

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I have a PDF file on my Firebase. I am using the [AndroidPDFViewer library](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer).  Then I retrieve data using `AsyncTask`.

I want to know how to stop my ProgressBar using the `isFinishedI()` function in my view class, as this while loop doesn't exit ?

```
public class PDFHandler {

    private PDFView pdfView =  null;
    private RetriverPDFStream retriverPDFStream;

    private RetriverPDFStream getRetriverPDFStream(){ return this.retriverPDFStream; }

    public void setPdfView(PDFView pdfView)
    {
        this.pdfView = pdfView;
    }

    public void openOnline(String link)
    {
        retriverPDFStream = new RetriverPDFStream();
        retriverPDFStream.execute(link);
    }

    public boolean isFinished ()
    {
        if(getRetriverPDFStream().getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }


    //This class to retrieve pdf online asynchronously
    public class RetriverPDFStream extends AsyncTask<String,Void, InputStream> {

        @Override
        protected InputStream doInBackground(String... strings) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try{
                URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                if(urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200)
                {
                    inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                }
            }catch (IOException e){
                return null;
            }
            return inputStream;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(InputStream inputStream) {
            pdfView.fromStream(inputStream).load();
        }
    }
}
```

On create method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    //This is function read PDF from URL
    PDFHandler pdfHandler = new PDFHandler();
    pdfHandler.setPdfView(pdfView);
    pdfHandler.openOnline(link);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    while(!pdfHandler.isFinished()){
         progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: Careful: when using the `while` loop, you're blocking the entire application UI (it can't move on to render views, catch user input, etc) until that finishes. You need to add a callback to the task

Comment: it is better if you create an interface in the asyncTask and implement it in your activity. can you share the full code

Comment: I shared it, please review it

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isFinished ()
{
    if(getRetriverPDFStream().getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
    {
        return true;
     }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```